# cakephp - apache - turn off directory browing of tmp folder

Tags: cakephp, apache2, cakephp-2.0

It seems cake's tmp folder is browse-able (if you go to localhost/tmp it shows all the files I put there), how can I turn this off without breaking anything?

I tried adding .hacccess file to that folder with -  Options -Indexes  - didn't work
I tried adding index.html - didn't work.

I am afraid to mess with the apache config files because it was a nightmare to get cake & php and everything working properly....

Why would cake have this on by default, isnt it a security issue? (at least the scan tool my client ran flagged it).

thanks
Joel

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your setup that has nothing to do with CakePHP. Your webroot (http://localhost) should be at this location: `app/webroot` and the tmp should be at `app/tmp`. In order for you do access `http://localhost/tmp`, tmp would have to be at app/webroot/tmp or you are redirecting it, which is not how CakePHP is designed to be setup.

Comment: If I do this `http://mydomain.com/tmp` on my CakePHP 2.x site, I get `Error: TmpController could not be found.`

Comment: ugh, it looks like someone added a tmp folder under webroot, thanks for the advice, problem solved, you want to answer it, @A_Santiago - I can mark it answered, thanks Joel!

Comment: Ok.. glad that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is definitely wrong with your setup that has nothing to do with CakePHP. Your webroot (localhost) should be at this location: `app/webroot` and the tmp should be at app/tmp. In order for you do access `http://localhost/tmp`, tmp would have to be at `app/webroot/tmp` or you are redirecting it, which is not how CakePHP is designed to be setup.